# Samsung and dispatchGesture funcrion

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, accessibilityservice, samsung-knox

As always, Samsung seems to like doing stuff their way.

I am building an accessibility service which has to dispatch a gesture every so often, and as far as I've gotten it gets the job done on the pixel emulators.
But every time I try it on the Samsung device, the program seems to just skip the dispatchGesture() call

Anybody got experience with that behaviour?

P.s might it be related to Knox?